# Setting up Google Analytics for multiple subdomains

Tags: google-analytics

so first here's a snippet of my current Analytics javascript:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-30490730-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.apartmentjunkie.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setSiteSpeedSampleRate', 100]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

So if you wanna have a quick peak at the site the url is [ApartmentJunkie.com](http://www.apartmentjunkie.com/), keep in mind the site is pretty bare bones but you'll get the idea -- basically it's very similar to craigslist in the sense that it's in the local space so people pick a city then get sent to a subdomain that is specific for that city, e.g. `winnipeg.mb.apartmentjunkie.com`.

I put that up late last night then had a look at the analytics and found that I am seeing only the request uri portion of the URLs in analytics as I would with any other site only with this one it's a problem as `winnipeg.mb.apartmentjunkie.com/map/` and `brandon.mb.apartmentjunkie.com/map/` are two different pages and shouldn't be lumped together as `/map/`

I know the kneejerk response is likely going to be "hey just setup a different google analytics profile for each subdomain" but there will eventually be a lot of subdomains so google's cap of 50 is going to be too limited and even more important I want to see the data in aggregate for the most part.

I am thinking of making a change to the javascript, to something like:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview',String(document.domain) + String(document.location)]);
```

But am unsure if this is the best way and figured someone else on so would have had a similar situation that they could talk a bit about.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the domain name to the reports in GA by adding a filter.

First, if you haven't done so already, create a "raw" unfiltered profile. In the event that a filter works so good that it filters ALL the data, you will have this one to fall back on.

On the "default" profile, add a hostname filter so you can distinguish between two like-named page. See [Profiles on GA's docs](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html#profilesKey) and the screen shot below for more info:

[image]